# Centering a footer list and making its elements all the same width

Tags: html, css

I've been working on some code, however css is being really arrogant to me and it wont let me make my circle list items all the same width and height :( also, when i created the footer, my list wont center in the page and sticks to the left.

Here is the code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>PAGE | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/page.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <ul>
                <li><a>0</a></li>
                <li><a>1</a></li>
                <li><a>2</a></li>
                <li><a>3/a></li>
                <li><a>4</a></li>
                <li><a>5</a></li>
                <li><a>6</a></li>
                <li><a>7</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.loginFrame {
position: fixed;
border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 60%);
border-radius: 2px;
background-color: #EAEAEA;
padding: 40px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px hsl(0, 0%, 60%);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px hsl(0, 0%, 60%);
box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px hsl(0, 0%, 60%);
}

.logo {
background: url("../img/logo.png") no-repeat center center;
height: 157px;
width: 477px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-left: -238.5px;
margin-top: -78.5px;
opacity:0.6;
filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}

.wrapper {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position: relative;
min-height: 99%;
}

.footer{
height: 50px;
bottom: 3;
width: inherit;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
}
.footer ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: inline;
}
.footer ul li {
display: inline;
list-style: none;

}
.footer ul li:after {
content: " ";
}
.footer ul li:last-child:after {
content: "";
}
.footer ul li a {
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 50%;
color: white;
background-color: #3061a3;
padding: 20px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
margin: 0 8px;
}
.footer ul li a:hover {
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #3974c3;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: picture]

If anyone can help me solve the problem, the help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :D

~ rkshah

Comment: to align things in center, use `width:90%;margin:0 auto` to your footer class.

Comment: Thanks its now centered, i just need to fix the issue of them not being all the same size :(

Answer (score 0):

set `text-align:center` for your footer `<ul>` for centering menu items:

```
.footer ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: inline;
text-align:center;  /* added */
}
```

set `display:block` to `<a>` in your footer menu for customize width:

```
.footer ul li a {
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 50%;
color: white;
background-color: #3061a3;
padding: 20px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
margin: 0 8px;
display:block;  /* added */
}
```

Comment: They're all the same size now, however they are all aligned vertically and not horizontally down the page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41312/discussion-between-user2972107-and-rshah)

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this:

**CSS**

```
#navigation_center ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}

#navigation_center ul li { display: inline; }

#navigation_center ul li a
{
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue","Helvetica",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    color: #DDD;
    background-color: #0099CF;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#navigation_center ul li a:hover
{
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #00BEF9;
}
```

**HTML**

```
   <div id="navigation_center">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```